# Data migration from On-premises to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration

We have Data Management Gateway that migrates data from on-premises to Azure. Is there anything similar to Data Management Gateway that supports migration from on-premises to Amazon Cloud?

UPDATE:

Let's assume I have a file on my OnPrem server which is updated on a regular basis (by some external process). Let's also assume the file refresh is completed by a pre-determined time (say 10 pm CET). Now from AWS, I need to be able to schedule an operation which will copy this file from my OnPrem server to my AWS S3 storage.

Options that I have now:
1. Have a python script running on my OnPrem server which will push the updated file to the S3 storage
2. Use Storage Gateway and map the folder to a S3 bucket. So, if the file is refreshed, it is immediately available in S3.

I am looking for a 3rd option. With Azure, we can use Azure Data Factory with a tool provided by Microsoft called "Data Management Gateway". This tool is installed on your OnPrem server and with it, you will be able to access any folder on the server from the Azure management portal.

Option 2 in AWS is not the same thing because you need to map the folders before hand. The Data Management Gateway in Azure is far more flexible. Is there an AWS equivalent?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you possibly provide more information? For example, what are you wanting to migrate? eg Virtual machines, files, database? Any additional information would assist in answering your question.

Comment: Have you looked at [AWS Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/)?

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 1):

In azure you can use logic apps to run on a particular time. It can connect with the data gateway and get the files copied to blob storage.